# ffmpeg fixed video noise reduction

Tags: ffmpeg, noise-reduction

I have a camera with a fixed noise ([video sample](https://youtu.be/pl1V9rpm3MM)). Is it possible to remove this noise completely using ffmpeg?

I tried ffmpeg "-vf" noise reduction but didn't find any way to remove the noise by supplying a noise mask.